# Format a number containing a decimal point with leading zeroes

Tags: python, string-formatting, decimal-point

I want to format a number with a decimal point in it with leading zeros.

This

```
>>> '3.3'.zfill(5)
003.3
```

considers all the digits and even the decimal point. Is there a function in python that considers only the whole part?

I only need to format simple numbers with no more than five decimal places. Also, using `%5f` seems to consider trailing instead of leading zeros.

Comment: Did you try `%5.1f` yet?  If so, what's wrong with that?

Comment: It pads the string with spaces and still considers the decimal point and everything after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with a string as your example does, you could write a small function such as this to do what you want:

```
def zpad(val, n):
    bits = val.split('.')
    return "%s.%s" % (bits[0].zfill(n), bits[1])

>>> zpad('3.3', 5)
'00003.3'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't want to do, But if there's no built-in function, I guess it will work. Thanks.

Comment: @3ee3 Try this on `'3'`. If you want a version that works on `int`s as well as `float`s, add a line `bits[0] = bits[0].zfill(n)` before the `return`, and change the `return` to `return bits = '.'.join(bits)`.
`

Comment: What about `-3.3`? Doesn't  produce expected results!! Add a condition `if val.count('-')>0:
        n=n+1` then it will work for that as well

Answer (score 30):

Is that what you look for?

```
>>> "%07.1f" % 2.11
'00002.1'
```

So according to your comment, I can come up with this one (although not as elegant anymore):

```
>>> fmt = lambda x : "%04d" % x + str(x%1)[1:]
>>> fmt(3.1)
0003.1
>>> fmt(3.158)
0003.158
```

Answer (score 18):

I like the new style of formatting.

```
loop = 2
pause = 2
print 'Begin Loop {0}, {1:06.2f} Seconds Pause'.format(loop, pause)
>>>Begin Loop 2, 0002.1 Seconds Pause
```

In {1:06.2f}:

- 1 is the place holder for variable pause
- 0 indicates to pad with leading zeros
- 6 total number of characters including the decimal point
- 2 the precision
- f converts integers to floats

Comment: Works perfectly! Just small changes for Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

```
print('{0:07.3f}'.format(12.34))
```

This will have total 7 characters including 3 decimal points, ie. "012.340"

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
>>> '%#05.1f' % 3.3
'003.3'
```

Comment: It still considers the fraction part, and cuts off anything after the first decimal place

Comment: So take into account the number of fraction digits, and add them into the decimal digit specifier.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.6+ you can use the fstring method:

```
f'{3.3:.0f}'[-5:]
>>> '3'

f'{30000.3:.0f}'[-5:]
>>> '30000'
```

This method will eliminate the fractional component (consider only the whole part) and return up to 5 digits.  Two caveats: First, if the whole part is larger than 5 digits, the most significant digits beyond 5 will be removed.
Second, if the fractional component is greater than 0.5, the function will round up.

```
f'{300000.51:.0f}'[-5:]
>>>'00001'
```