# Python formatting leading zeros and optional decimals

Tags: python

I'm trying to format some numbers in Python in the following way:

```
(number) -> (formatted number)
1 -> 01
10 -> 10
1.1 -> 01.1
10.1 -> 10.1
1.1234 -> 01.1
```

What formatting specification could I use for that?

What I've tried: `{:04.1f}` doesn't work correctly if there's no decimal part, while `{:0>2}` only works for integers, `{:0.2g}` comes close but doesn't add the leading zero and `{:0>4.2g}` adds too many zeroes if there's no decimal part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format comes close btw, but isn't a duplicate since my leading zero requires a different answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a number containing a decimal point with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407766/format-a-number-containing-a-decimal-point-with-leading-zeroes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't want a decimal point for special cases, there is no formatting rule.

Workaround:

```
"{:04.1f}".format(number).replace(".0", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hackish answer:

```
l = [1, 10, 1.1, 10.1, 1.1234]
s = lambda n: '{{{}}}'.format(':04.1f' if isinstance(n, float) else ':02').format(n)

for i in l:
    print(s(i))

# 01
# 10
# 01.1
# 10.1
# 01.1
```

The other two answers are both superior IMO.  This is just a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would branch on whether your number is an integer or a float:

```
if isinstance(number, int):
    print('{:0>2}'.format(number))
elif isinstance(number, float):
    print('{:04.1f}'.format(number))
```